# How can I skip query if where_in clause is empty in MyBatis 3?

Tags: mybatis

```
select * from users where id in ()
```

The query is shown above.

```
<select id="getByIds" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    SELECT
    <include refid="BaseColumnList"/>
    FROM users
    WHERE id IN
    <foreach item="id" collection="ids"
             open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

If the Param `ids` is empty, Mybatis will throw BadSqlGrammarException, which generate a query like '`select * from users where id in`'.

How can I skip query and return empty list if `ids` is empty?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can I skip query and return empty list if ids is empty?

To **skip** the query (not execute it), just don't call Mybatis.
The calling code should check if *ids* is empty:

```
return null == ids || ids.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<User>() : session.select("getByIds", ids);
```

This is exactly what is asked in the question.

If you really want Mybatis to handle this, then produced query must be valid because must be executed (then  not skipped) to return empty result **quickly**. that means forget something like  `id  = <!-- a value that will never exist in the table -->` because it could surely involve a (free and useless) full scan to search the unexisting value.
Then:

```
    WHERE 
    <choose>
        <when test="ids==null || ids.isEmpty()">
            1 = 0 <!-- a test returning false, to adapt depending on you DB vendor -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            id IN <foreach item="id" collection="ids" open="(" separator="," close=")">#{id}</foreach>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
```

Another option to confirm would consist in using interceptors to "cancel" the query before its execution, but this is definitely overkill complexity for what has to be achieved here.

Comment: I use mapper interface, so I move the checking to the service layer : if parameter is not empty, then call dao.

Comment: I was not aware that you could (effectively) use java code in the test attribute ... am I taking that too far? or is it true with restrictions? plus one from me!

Answer (score 7):

**java code function**

```
 List<ApiPriceChlogEntity> getApiAndDevPrice(@Param("apiKeys") List<String> currentApiKey, @Param("devKeys") List<String> currentDevKey, @Param("startDate") Date startDate);
```

**the mapper file**

```
<select id="getApiAndDevPrice"  resultMap="BaseResultMap">
SELECT
<include refid="Base_Column_List"/>
FROM t_api_price_chlog tab1
<where>
    <if test="apiKeys.size() > 0">
      tab1.api_key IN
      <foreach collection="apiKeys" item="item" separator="," open="(" close=")" index="">
        #{item}
      </foreach>
    </if>
    <if test="devKeys.size() > 0">
      AND tab1.dev_key IN
      <foreach collection="devKeys" item="item" separator="," open="(" close=")" index="">
        #{item}
      </foreach>
    </if>

    <if test="startDate != null">
      AND tab1.change_date >= #{startDate}
    </if>
</where>
```

I have test it,hope to help u.

Comment: this cause query all data if parameter has no value

Answer (score 0):

Using test:

```
<select id="getByIds" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    SELECT
    <include refid="BaseColumnList"/>
    FROM users
<if test="ids!= null">
    WHERE id IN
    <foreach item="id" collection="ids"
             open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{id}
    </foreach>
</if>
</select>
```

Comment: this will produce a valid query that will be executed and will return all users unlike what OP asked for.

Comment: @blackwizard the query will not be valid if the collection is empty, a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` will be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Use mybatis Interceptor, create a nil PreparedStatement Object and return it.

```
@Intercepts({@Signature(type = StatementHandler.class, method = "prepare", args = {Connection.class, Integer.class}),
    @Signature(type = ResultSetHandler.class, method = "handleResultSets", args = {Statement.class})})
@Slf4j
public class MyBatisInterceptor implements Interceptor {
   @Override
   public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      //...your code
      //return invocation.proceed();
      return new NullExecutor();
   }
}
```

MyBatis wants to get a PreparedStatement Object as a return value, the "NullExecutor" is:

```
public class NullExecutor implements PreparedStatement {}
```

Nothing todo, just write few thing, like:

```
@Override
public void setDouble(int parameterIndex, double x) throws SQLException {
    //empty here
}
@Override
public boolean execute() throws SQLException {
    //it's ok,do noting.
    return false;
}
...etc
```

Add your configuration:

```
@Bean
public MyBatisInterceptor myBatisInterceptor() {
    return new MyBatisInterceptor();
}
```

You need to get the "BoundSql" in Interceptor, then you can get sql and args, just google it.

I'm not sure it can work, just for learning.